# Why passing variable into function that takes pointers as argument works?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(int *a, int *b){
    int temp;
    temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}

int main() {
    int x=5;
    int y=10;
    swap(x,y);
    cout<<x<<" "<<y;
    return 0;
}
```

I have the code above, I thought that an error would occur as I did not pass the address but 'x', 'y' were swapped. So I am wondering if the community can help me explaining why this work?

I guess there is some "casting" like behaviour but I am not sure

Comment: I seriously doubt that you provided a [mre], seeing that `\b` where I'd expect a `*b`. Please double check that you are according to [ask].

Comment: Your version of `swap` is not called. **This is exactly why `using namespace std;` should be avoided.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/whats-the-problem-with-using-namespace-std

Comment: `using namespace std;` and naming functions after standard ones leads to all sorts of UBs. Actually even removing `using namespace std;`  might not help in some cases, becuase some functions can be imported from global namespace